# Value search within range (INDEX/VLOOKUP)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have unfiltered range of values, they act as a key indicator in finding needed value result.

In search box I have three variables :**state, item name, value**. My goal is to find **result** based on these inputus.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/6tvIHn8.jpg]

Have tried INDEX LARGE, but it worked only with sorted values. It seems, that the problem occurs only with unfiltered results, but it's not a solution.

Values I will be looking for, 9 out 10 times falls within these ranges (not exact match).

Sorry, I misspelled it. Result shuold be **4.38**

Example: If entered CA/CAR/250001 it shuold return **4.38**.

Comment: will value be an exact match?

Comment: You could have an extra column concatenating A,B,C and then vlookup that column wherever you need.

Comment: You would need to sort your data if *"not exact match"* is needed.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a distance column with formula `=IF(OR(C:C-$I$3<0,A:A<>$I$1,B:B<>$I$2),1E+99,C:C-$I$3)`
- Result formula: `=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(MINIFS(E:E,A:A,$I$1,B:B,$I$2),E:E,0))`

[image]

It uses the `Value = 250001` to calculate the distance to the `Result`. Negative values are set to a very high value `1E+99` = 1×10⁹⁹. Then we can use `MinIfs` to find the minimum distance of a given `State` and `Item` and finally we use `Match` and `Index` to turn the minimum into the `Result`.

Comment: You do not need the helper: `=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(MINIFS(C:C,A:A,$I$1,B:B,$I$2,C:C,">="&I3),C:C,0))` But you do not take into account the matching again on A and B so it will return false positives if there are different A and B in the list and a distance is the same.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah damn you are right but I could take account in the helper column `=IF(OR(C:C-$I$3<0,A:A<>$I$1,B:B<>$I$2),1E+99,C:C-$I$3)` and then it works because all the others will be `1E+99`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMIFS() with MINIFS() as criteria

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,G2,B:B,G3,C:C,MINIFS(C:C,A:A,G2,B:B,G3,C:C,">="&G4))
```

One Note:  This assumes that the combination of State,Item,Value are unique.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

If one does not have access to MINIFS one can use AGGREGATE in its place:

```
AGGREGATE(15,7,C2:C17/((A2:A17=G2)*(B2:B17=G3)*(C2:C17>=G4)),1)
```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: That's almost perfect. But due to my error in question,  250001 shuold return 4,38. Any suggestions ? I have tried, but I'm unfamiliar with Aggregate.

Comment: You would want to change the `15` to `14` in the first criterion in the AGGREGATE and change the `(C2:C17>=G4)` to `(C2:C17<=G4)`